# Error in mail scripts - where to start?

Tags: php, email

I got handed a mailing script (as part of a bigger CMS) that is not sending any emails. And I can't for the life of me figure out why it´s not sending any emails. I added some more error handlings (that I found on other questions) and checked my error logs but to no avail.

This is the code, I have removed the `body` and `title` of the code for privacy. However, the problem is not in there since I tried sending it with just plain text.

```
<?php include '../includes/header.php' ; ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vidvdcms/css/formstyle.css" />
<?php

// For testing only
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$result =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klant, bestellingen WHERE klant.klant_id LIKE '".$_GET['mail']."' ORDER BY bestellingen.order_id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

// multiple recipients

$to = ''.$row['email'].'';
$name = '' . $row['voornaam'] . ' ' . $row['achternaam'] . ''; 

// subject
$subject = 'REDACTED - SUBJECT OF EMAIL';

// message
$message = 'REDACTED - BODY OF MAIL WITH HTML/GETS';

}


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: XXXX <XXX@emaple.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: XXX@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

print "REDACTED - Email sent succesful message"; 

mysql_close($link)
?>
```

**Edit**: I have triple checked the code, and it seems to work fine. I tried a simple mail scripts found online, and that **did not send either**. I tried it on another server, and it sent. So I think it's the server? How do I check this? What do i try next?

Comment: Did it work before? Is the IP blocked by your ISP? Is the query even working? <?php print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result)); ?>

Comment: It did work before, but it "stopped worked suddenly". I'm going to check now if I can still send mails on this server. Good suggestion. Query works, yes, I get a big array of all data entered previously.

Comment: So I think its the ISP? I tried a simple mail script that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is about how to debug properly:

Where to start would be to enable all PHP logging:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Then see what you get on screen.

You also need to locate the logs on your mail server and see whether you have any messages in there.

If that doesn't help, get [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) working and step through the code line by line in your IDE (Google for Xdebug setup instructions for your specific IDE) to see whether all the variables are as you expect.

If you want specific help with solving this problem, you'll need to paste some error output from the above steps.

Comment: Thank you, no I wanted some pointers on where to start searching. I'll get working!